# How to set the equation no with quad space to equation

Tags: spacing, equations, numbering

How to set the equation no with quad space to equation content (centered) like below

```
Sample Text  Sample Text   Sample Text

             (1.1)  A + b = 20

Sample Text
```

Can anyone suggest how to get these output.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

As a once-off, you can set it manually using the construction below with `\numeq`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\newcommand{\numeq}{\refstepcounter{equation}\textup{(\theequation)}\quad}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Sample text sample text sample text
\[
  \numeq A + b = 20 \label{eqn:stuff}
\]
Sample text and see~(\ref{eqn:stuff}).
\end{document}
```

For an automated way of adding these to equations, you could add

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\[}{\numeq}
\makeatother
```

to your document preamble. This would make all formerly unnumbered equations now numbered. But without more detail, I'm not sure what scope we're talking about.